# ISO2USB vs Universal USB Installer vs LinuxLive USB Creator for a CentOS 5.9 install

Tags: centos, installation, centos5, usb-flash-drive

Is there any functional difference among [these](http://iso2usb.sourceforge.net/) [three](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) [tools](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/), if I want to create a CentOS 5.9 bootable USB installer using a Windows box?  I realize ISO2USB was more CentOS-specific, but also that general-purpose Linux tools have come a long way and have a larger following, although not necessarily of CentOS users.

ISO2USB forces you to use FAT32, which it then cannot copy DVD ISOs onto because they are larger than the largest allowed filesize.

UUI doesn't let you select the file because it's looking for something with `LiveCD` in the name.

I guess that leaves LLUC, which doesn't appear to have an option to point to a second DVD ISO, so I'm not sure if/how this is going to work.

Comment: I prefer http://www.linuxliveusb.com/

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff, thanks, I've updated the question.  Feel free to give an answer with specific reasons re: CentOS with your preference... also btw CentOS 5.9 is not listed as specifically supported on their site, and I'm asking about an installer rather than a LiveCD, but of course a live version would still let me install to hard disk, I assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ISO2USB.

UUI doesn't let you select the file because it's looking for something with `LiveCD` in the name.  LLUC has similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). I've used it for CentOS, Ubuntu and Clonezilla and it's never given me any issues.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is installing, there will be no functional difference in the final installed product. User experience setting up the USB drive and booting the USB drive will differ, but that has hardly any impact on using them to install.

Comment: Of course, but the "function" here I mean is in the experience.  Why are there three tools?  Is one faster to set up, less finicky, etc. than the others?

Comment: Why is there more than one tool available? Because people like to make stuff. The speed is not going vary much between the tools. So concentrate on features important to you. I only have extensive experience with pendrivelinux.com and Ubuntu.

Comment: and what such features might there be?  I'm not sure what's important to me if I don't know what differences to consider.